# Package Manager Console Warning - There is already a version of EntityFramework.dll loaded. You may need

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

Using VS 2015 Community (but this is also happening in VS2013)
.NET 4
EF 4.3.1 originally installed via nuget
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.2.0.10516

In the package manager console I get this warning when I start up one of my projects

> There is already a version of EntityFramework.dll loaded. You may need
>   to restart Visual Studio for the commands to work properly.

The only refererence to Entity Framework in Packages.config is

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Which seems good.

Anyone know whats going on?